# R Markdown (beamer) - how to create 2 columns

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer, presentation

I am trying to create a presentation using RMarkdown beamer. I want a slide to have 2 columns and this is what I have so far:

```
---
title: title

author: name
        
date: date

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true

linkcolor: false
---
    
## TEST

\footnotesize
\justify
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
- I will write something here tex text text tex text text tex text text
:::
::: {.column}
- And then something here tex text text tex text text tex text text tex text text
:::
::::::::::::::
```

The header.tex's content is:

```
\definecolor{mycolorlightblue}{RGB}{103,153,200}
\definecolor{mycolordarkblue}{RGB}{0,70,127}
% add packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% remove 2nd section from header
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother
% change colour of lines
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=mycolorlightblue}
% text title
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
% text colour
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
% item colour
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
% define colour text
% \usebeamerfont{section title}\color{blue!70!green}\insertsection\par
% no header or footer on first page
\thispagestyle{empty}
% remove title slides at beginning of sections
\AtBeginSection{}
% add page counter to the footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(155,0){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[]{ALL-ICONS.png}}}
  \end{picture}}
```

This is the result I am seeing, almost perfect, but the 2nd column starts slight below the first one, as shown below, do you understand why?

[image]

correspondent .tex file to the .rmd:

```
\begin{frame}{TEST}
\protect\hypertarget{test}{}

\footnotesize
\justify

\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  I will write something here text text text text text text text text
  text text text text text text text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  And then something here text text text text text text text text text
  text text text text text text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Can you post the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Many thanks Sam. I've just edited my question with .tex content as requested. Do you have any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Thanks to the option `keep_tex: true`, there should be a `.tex ` with the same name as your `.rmd` file. Can you post it, so we see the code used for the columns?

Comment: Many thanks Sam. Ive just edited my question to include the code part of the .tex file that is used for the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `\justify`, it should be `\justifying` instead (but at the position you use it, it won't have any effect on the text in the columns anyway, so you could also just remove it ...)

```
---
title: title

author: name
        
date: date

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true
---
    
## TEST

\footnotesize
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
- I will write something here tex text text tex text text tex text text
:::
::: {.column}
- And then something here tex text text tex text text tex text text tex text text
:::
::::::::::::::
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: what is the reason for of `:::::::::::::: {.columns}` followed by `::: {.column}`? Would `::: columns` and then `:::: column` also. lead to the same set of columns? (Or are there any differences, e.g., of content alignment?

Comment: @mavericks I have no idea

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz By chance, do you know if I can pass further arguments to make adjustments to vertical alignment? Maybe similar to width `{.column width=30%}`?

Comment: @mavericks You can use `::: {.column width="30%"}`