# Vertically center-align content of columns in a beamer presentation generated with rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

How to vertically center-align the content of multiple columns in a `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation?

As recommended in a comment in to an answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090573/r-markdown-beamer-how-to-create-2-columns/66100944?noredirect=1#comment117206365_66100944), I tried `::: {.column width="30%"}`, which however did not work for me.

[image]

If there is a simple way to align content *differently for each column*, that would further be very helpful too (e.g., c1: top, c2: middle, c3: bottom, c4: middle).

### MWE

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true
---

## Figures in columns top-aligned
::: columns

:::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r top-p-5, echo=FALSE, out.width='30%'}
plot(pressure[1:5,])
```
::::

:::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r top-p-10, echo=FALSE, out.width='50%'}
plot(pressure[1:10,])
```
::::

:::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r top-p-all, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
plot(pressure[1:nrow(pressure),])
```
::::

:::

## Figures in columns center-aligned (not working)
::: columns

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-5, echo=FALSE, out.width='30%'}
plot(pressure[1:5,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-10, echo=FALSE, out.width='50%'}
plot(pressure[1:10,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-all, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
plot(pressure[1:nrow(pressure),])
```
:::

:::
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:::: {.columns align=center}` to get centre alignment

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true
---

## Figures in columns top-aligned
::: columns

:::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r top-p-5, echo=FALSE, out.width='30%'}
plot(pressure[1:5,])
```
::::

:::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r top-p-10, echo=FALSE, out.width='50%'}
plot(pressure[1:10,])
```
::::

:::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r top-p-all, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
plot(pressure[1:nrow(pressure),])
```
::::

:::

## Figures in columns center-aligned (not working)
:::: {.columns align=center}

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-5, echo=FALSE, out.width='30%'}
plot(pressure[1:5,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-10, echo=FALSE, out.width='50%'}
plot(pressure[1:10,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-all, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
plot(pressure[1:nrow(pressure),])
```
:::

::::
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Your proposal unfortunately not work for me somehow. My sessionInfo `R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)`, `Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)`, `Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6`, `knitr_1.30`, `rmarkdown_2.5`

Comment: @mavericks It seems to work with `R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"` on rstudio cloud https://rstudio.cloud/project/2224516

Comment: can confirm that works on rstudio cloud. Updating "bookdown", "kableExtra", "knitr", "markdown" did not help. Will try to upgrade to `R 4.0.3` later today

Comment: upgraded to the latest version of R (`4.04`), updated all packages to be at least as new as the ones used by Rstudio cloud. And yet, the PDF compiled still shows all 3 plots top-aligned :(
So odd that the same code leads to different results on Rstudio locally and on Rstudio cloud!

Comment: @mavericks Did you also check the version of pandoc?

Comment: `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` yielded that `2.9.2.1` is installed, so it looks pretty up-to-date.

Comment: @marvericks The latest pandoc version is [2.11.4](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.11.4) as of 2021/02/24. Yours may be "too old" to get centre-aligned columns. [This chapter of *R Markdown Cookbook*](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html) guides you to use  Pandoc version(s) not bundled with the RStudio IDE if you want to do so.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera Thanks a lot for the hint! Indeed, `Rstudio Cloud` is working with the newer `pandoc 2.11.2`.

Comment: For anyone else experiencing similar problems: Check the version of your local `pandoc` with `rmarkdown::find_pandoc()`. If it is "outdated", update `pandoc` using [brew](https://docs.zettlr.com/en/installing-pandoc) or install the [latest version from GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases).
Run `rmarkdown::find_pandoc(version = "X.Y.Z")` (e.g.,  `rmarkdown::find_pandoc(version = "2.11.4")`) to inform rmarkdown of the change.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the helpful answer from @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the following approach can be employed to align content differently in each column:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
# CHECK PANDOC VERSION
library(rmarkdown)
if (pandoc_available())
  cat("pandoc", as.character(pandoc_version()), "is available\n (pandoc >2.11.2 is required)")
```

## Figures in columns center-aligned (set for all columns at once)
:::: {.columns align=center}

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-5, echo=FALSE, out.width='30%'}
plot(pressure[1:5,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-10, echo=FALSE, out.width='50%'}
plot(pressure[1:10,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%"}
```{r center-p-all, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
plot(pressure[1:nrow(pressure),])
```
:::

::::


## Figures in columns aligned differently (set for separately for each column)
:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="30%" align=center}
center
```{r 3-center-p-5, echo=FALSE, out.width='30%'}
plot(pressure[1:5,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%" align=top}
top
```{r 3-top-p-10, echo=FALSE, out.width='50%'}
plot(pressure[1:10,])
```
:::

::: {.column width="30%" align=bottom}
bottom
```{r 3-bottom-p-all, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
plot(pressure[1:nrow(pressure),])
```
:::

::::
````

[image]